# Debugging Javascript on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, firebug, firebug-lite

I was wondering if there are any useful tools people have found to debug javascript on an iPad which is not jail broken.  It is an iPad supplied for work so jail breaking is not an option.  Through some tedious steps I have gotten firebug-lite working on the iPad but my debugger statements in the javascript are not being hit.  There is also no capability that I am seeing to set breakpoints as you can traditionally with Firebug.

I also have Safari's debug console open but that is fairly useless for what I am trying to accomplish.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Some options I put into a blog post: http://uxformobile.com/tips-for-debugging-on-the-ios-app

Comment: @Jeff Fol : Out of curiosity, why do you want to debug only on an Ipad ?

Comment: I am having a bug occur only on the iPad and not on any other platforms including Safari.  So I was hoping to narrow down what the issue was since I am fairly certain it is related to the javascript.

Comment: @DA firebug is including all the functionality in that link and as I said in the post I already have the console window enabled.

Comment: Safari has a debug console on the iPad.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Did you look at [webkit remote debugging protocol](http://www.webkit.org/blog/1620/webkit-remote-debugging/)? It seems they know people want a debugger for their iPad but still no real world native iPad remote debugger is available out there.

But don't get disappointed, there is a tool called [weinre](https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) that doing what webkit folks willing to do in the future right now!

**Update:**

By release of [**Google Chrome for Android phones remote debugging**](http://code.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging.html) and tablets debugging mobile web apps is no pain anymore. You will need an expensive Google Galaxy Nexus phone with ICS on it to do it. But future is bright! Check out the video demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4zpL4VBbuU&feature=player_embedded):

> weinre is Web Inspector Remote. Pronounced like the word "winery". Or
>   maybe like the word "weiner". Who knows, really.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I'll give it a try when I'm back in the office.

Comment: weinre link is broken. Please, could you fix it?

Answer (score 5):

For those coming to this question from Google, there is now a [Web Inspector available in iOS Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/) (scroll down to "Safari on iOS"). Note that it requires a Mac computer to use.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is broken.

Comment: I think this only works if you have your iOS device connected to a Mac, is that right?

Comment: Yes, this only works if you have it connected to a mac.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite)?

I haven't used it on the iPad, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

I'd probably set a conditional include based on if a query param is set - for instance (php)

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['debug'])): ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="firebuglite.js"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: As per my OP I have already mentioned having firebug lite configured and working.  Unfortunately I am not able to set breakpoints in my javascript and debugger statements are not causing the execution of javascript to stop.

Comment: Thanks, it works in Safari on iOS 9, not perfect in displaying CSS, but the console works fine.
I included the parameter to show the firebug automatically, so the link to it in my case was:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite.js#startOpened=true"></script>`

Comment: Unfortunately Firebug Lite is now dead. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try **iDebug**. You can direct download it from AppStore onto your iPad. [Here's the AppStore Link](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idebug/id525956537?mt=8).

Comment: What a terrible AppStore page. It tells you nothing at all about what iDebug actually does. And the support page appears to be a bunch of pictures of their other products.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently written a tool for showing console logs in a movable/resizable "window" (actually a div). It provides similar functionality to Firebug's console but you can see it over your page on a tablet. [Tablet/Smartphone/Phablet Debug Console](http://www.bagnall.co.uk/free_stuff/console/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Firefox's built in WebIDE with Valence

Plugin your device > in Firefox click on the spanner icon > find WebIDE > under "OTHER" click on "Safari, Firefox, and other WebViews on iOS"

[1] https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/mozilla-introduces-the-first-browser-built-for-developers-firefox-developer-edition/

[2] https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/06/webide-lands-in-nightly/

[3] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a way to debug a website in Safari on iOS using **Firefox WebIDE** on a Windows machine. I wrote an answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/35714835/306179 further describing this solution, as it was not necessarily straightforward to set up and use. It does not provide all the Developer Tools you would expect from, for instance, Chrome's DevTools suite, but it at least gives the Console, Inspector, and Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Apple Mac computer, you can connect it to your iPad.

First you must ensure that you have the Web Inspector enabled ("Settings > Safari > Advanced" and turn on "Web Inspector").

[image]

Then connect your iPad to your Mac via an USB cable.
After that I can choose in the "Develop" Menu of Safari to debug the website displayed on my iPad/iPhone.

[image]

Source of images and original information:
https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari--webdesign-8787

Comment: "Connect to your Mac" - useful for those with a Mac as well as the Ipad :P

Comment: Specific mac  version??? I'm still on Yosemite and I don't get much on the Console

Comment: @becker This should be available since Mountain Lion (Safari 6)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm allowed to re-post my answer from another question, as it's often frowned upon, but in [*Debug iPad Safari with a PC*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74900302/195835) I posted 3 options of JS console and logging tools that can assist with troubleshooting issues on iOS devices, with screenshots and sample code snippets. One of these is an open source tool I built myself, but the other two are probably even more advanced.

They all make up for the lack of a proper Javascript console and error log in iOS. There's also some additional tools mentioned in the link above. The answers there are likely relevant to this question also.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using Firebug Lite as a bookmarklet. You should be able to use all features without changing the code of your app as Jesse suggested. See [this link](http://iosbookmarklets.com/tutorials/firebug-lite-bookmarklet-ipad/).

Comment: Unfortunately this is now quite outdated. Firebug Lite does not really support modern iOS versions.

Answer (score -1):

Normally to debug js I would use console.log, but since you can't access the console (I couldn't since I didn't have a mac, only the ipad) I created a div with id = test123 on the page, and just output stuff into that. You can find null's or undefined that way. I know it's not the best, but it beats going out and buying a new mac.