# Debug iPad Safari with a PC

Tags: ios, ipad, debugging, mobile-safari

I want to test my website on Safari on my iPad. I only have another PC. Is there a way for me to do remote debugging like ADB (Android Debug Bridge) with mobile Chrome? I searched on StackOverflow, seems there is an Adobe Edge Inspect CC, but I don't know if this is a good choice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**2018 Update:**

Since the original post, the blog post is dead & [Telerik App Builder is discontinued](https://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/discontinuation) and no longer offered. Adding this update to inform readers in case they don't read the user comments that follow this answer post. As for the blog post, for those still interested, here's a [web cached copy](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://blog.falafel.com/ios-web-inspector-on-windows-with-telerik-appbuilder/&num=1&strip=0&vwsrc=0). Regarding the blog, I think the company that blog's from has since shut down.

When I get a chance, I'll see if I have a copy of the app builder saved so that I can post it online for those still interested in using it, along with another cached copy of the blog post maybe.

**Original Answer**

You can try option of using Telerik AppBuilder (Windows client) as a replacement on Windows for Safari debugger on Mac when remote debugging. There's a nice blog post about the steps to do it in link below. I'd rather not repost the info as there are also screenshots and it's a lot of text. But essentially, you install app, open it, connect device via USB, then you can find it in the app and open up the developer tools/debugger for it. For non-public websites, you'll have to open up port 80 with some firewall configs documented in the post.

http://blog.falafel.com/Blogs/josh-eastburn/2014/03/04/ios-web-inspector-on-windows-with-telerik-appbuilder

The tool requires a license or you can use the trial, which becomes a basic edition afterwards. I think the basic edition will still allow you to do the debugging. I'm going to try it out myself.

You can also try these iOS apps too, you can find them in the iTunes App store. They give you a built in developer tools feature (right on iOS no remote debug) that mobile Safari doesn't offer.

MIH Tool - basic edition
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mihtool/id584739126?ls=1&mt=8

HTTPWatch Basic
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/httpwatch-basic-http-sniffer/id658886056?mt=8

I gave them a try and they're at least better than the mobile Safari you get on iOS, unless one needs to target full mobile Safari compatibility. I'm guessing the pro/paid editions of those apps give you more/better features.

Comment: With the latest version of AppBuilder 2016.04.14.2 and iOS 9.1 I cannot get that to work according to the blog post. AppBuilder does not display the Web Inspector anymore. Anyone having similar issues?

Comment: The telerik option seems to require having an apple developer account and I was never able to get my device connect. I don't do any apple development, I just need to inspect and debug safari html/css defect.

Comment: The blog link is dead and Telerik Appbuilder is not accessible anymore :
https://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/discontinuation

Comment: That is unfortunate, it was good tool. I'll see if I have a cached copy locally somewhere that I could put up. But best to find other solutions now.

Comment: For those that might have copy of the old Appbuilder, here's cached copy of the tutorial: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://blog.falafel.com/ios-web-inspector-on-windows-with-telerik-appbuilder/&num=1&strip=0&vwsrc=0

Comment: Blog site is down.

Comment: The telerik app builder was retired

Comment: Do this still work? I've not been able to intall the npm package. It seems its not found.. An updated answer to this question would be very appreciated!

Comment: Did you not read the 2018 update? The tool is "gone" sadly.

Answer (score 93):

**Update October 2019**

This solution doesn't work for IOS 12+ ([resource 1](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter), [resource 2](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/issues/79)).

**Updated and tested on 24/6/2017**

Using **Chrome** on **Windows 8 and more recent**:

- Download and install [Node](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- Download and install ITunes and connect it to your Device. (A pop-up should shows to your iPad to get authorization)
  . Be sure to allow web inspector in your iPad
- Download and install the [remote webkit adapter](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter)

Using Powershell (As administrator):

`npm install remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter -g`

- Execute the adapter:

Using Powershell (as administrator):

`remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9000`

You should get a similar output:

`C:\Windows\system32> remotedebug_ios_webkit_adapter --port=9000
 remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter is listening on port 9000
 iosAdapter.getTargets
 ...`

- Open **Chrome** and go to the following link:

chrome://inspect/#devices

- Click on configure next to "Discover network targets" and add the following:
  **localhost:9000**

Make sure to have the web page you want debug open on safari, you should see it on chrome inspector page under **Remote Target**

**[Extra step for iOS 11](https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/issues/79)** Thanks to @skaurus

Comment: Excellent, this is by far the easiest solution. You can also use the built in DevTools by going to this link `chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?ws=localhost:9222/devtools/page/1`

Comment: I have tried the above on Windows 10, with Chrome and Canary, but Browser does not find device. I downloaded the latest iTunes today, executed iTunes with admin priv. and the same with the ios...proxy.exe. any thoughts?

Comment: @Highdown Is the webkit-debug-proxy showing an output similar to the one above?

Comment: @Lemmy4555: Yes. It found and connected to my iPad. The issue may be https. I need to debug with https for my web app. Any idea if https is supported? Thanks...

Comment: @Lemmy4555 Here is an error that displays in the developer tools: WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9222/devtools/page/1' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
WebInspector.loaded @ DevTools.js:3104

Comment: @Lemmy4555 A note for ios_webkit_debug_proxy.exe states:  Due to security reasons,  https  URLs will not work; use  http  or force-allow with the URL bar's shield icon. Not sure that this is the reason for my error above, since I did not get any security shield icon error. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Lemmy4555 What URL bar shield icon? In chrome, I see an i in a circle on one side, and a star on the other. In Safari, I see what looks like an 'align left' icon on one side, and the refresh icon on the other. Where should this shield be?

Comment: @nHaskins The schield icon means that page contains unsafe scripts, if it's not displaying don't care about it.

Comment: The [Firefox/Valence method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35714835/388994) seems to be much more stable now.

You may have issues using the latest Inspector, that I previously suggested, as the protocols for debugging Chrome and Safari started to diverge too much - see https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy#devtools-note

Comment: Managed to get this working in Windows 10 with iOS10. I needed to download the x64 build of the debugging proxy as the other build threw errors (Direct Link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32/files/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win64.zip/download) Also the URL blade provided didn't work for me, only the second URL did.

Comment: I got this to work on Windows 7 and iOS 10.3.2. @BenShelton's comment / solution got it working for me. Also had to update to the most current Chrome at time of writing Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit). iTunes 12.5.5.5 - not sure that matters

Comment: This was not working for me on Win 10 + iOS 11, but I found a solution here: https://github.com/RemoteDebug/remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter/issues/79

Comment: If you're behind a company proxy there's an additional step needed. In adapter.js and iosAdapter.js change "request(this._url)" to "request({'url':this._url, 'proxy': ''}"

Comment: This Answer is the perfect solution to be implemented, thank for this... But on web inspecting, after a while the Styles panel stucks and its doesnt show me the respective classes implemented on elements.. Did anyone else faced the issue?

Comment: Confirming that this is a working solution for Win 10 + iOS 10.

Comment: This is also working for me. The only thing that was not mentioned that I had to do before it worked, was restarting my PC after installing iTunes.

Answer (score 32):

**See [monkeythedev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786618/306179) for the easiest way to debug on a Windows 8+ machine with iOS 9+. I updated [my blog post](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) using information from that answer and other sources and also [recorded a screenshare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9vA_R3w6eE). The method below should still work for iOS 8 and down, if needed.**

There is actually a pretty easy way to debug a website in Safari on iOS using Firefox on a Windows machine.

*NOTE: Ryan wrote in the comments below that this may only work on iOS 8 and down. I am unable to confirm, but be aware.*

I wrote a [detailed blog post](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) about this, but here are the highlights:

1. Install iTunes to get the "Apple Mobile Device Support" and "Apple Application Support" applications that come with it. (uninstall iTunes afterward, if you want)
2. Connect your iOS device via USB.
3. [Enable web inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html) on iOS (available on iOS 6 and later).
4. Open Safari on your iOS device and browse to a website.
5. Open Firefox on your Windows machine and press *Shift + F8* to open WebIDE, which should include the necessary [Valance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence) add-on, if you use Firefox Developer Edition (any version) or Firefox 37 and later (any channel).
6. For some reason, I couldn't get it to connect to my iOS device until I downloaded the [ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32](https://github.com/artygus/ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32) program and ran it. It opens a blank Command Prompt, but after I went back to WebIDE after opening it, I disconnected, then reconnected, and I saw debug info for the website I had opened in Safari. You may not need to do this though, as another user just had to add an exception to their firewall then disconnect/reconnect, and it worked.

The debug info available isn't as exhaustive as Chrome Developer Tools (specifically no "Networking" tab), but it was enough for me to be able to view what was going on in the Console.

[image]

Comment: FYI, for the iTunes (driver/library) dependencies, if one doesn't want to install (then uninstall) iTunes, you could use a MSI/EXE extractor tool (or equivalent like WinRAR) to view/extract the iTunes installer content like a zip file, then keep only the driver/library files. They are the MSI files with the names mentioned. I always hated installing/using iTunes. The drivers are good to keep and reuse until you need new drivers (say for new Apple devices, new features, etc.)

Comment: I did not have to install the ios-webkit-proxy-win32 but I did get a firewall warning when I clicked to open the safari device. I made an exception but it still didn't work the first time, but after I disconnected and reconnected it worked great. This solution is by far the easiest I've found after hours of searching, you sir deserve all the upvotes.

Comment: As per this thread (https://github.com/mozilla/valence/issues/199), there seems to be some issues using this method with iOS 9

Comment: I also had to download ios-webkit-debug-proxy-win32 (had to take the ios-webkit-debug-proxy-mingw32 version). Still it didn't work. Then I clicked "Chrome Desktop" in the WebIDE and now it works!

Comment: I don't think it works past iOS 8, as mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Valence. It's not working for me on iOS 10.

Answer (score 9):

This question was more than 4 years ago, but I feel like it's worth to mention another option which is platform-independent which seems is not mentioned above:

**VConsole**

It's a JavaScript that you can inject into your page(s) which will overwrite all native console output and show it as an overlay on top of your page content, in a level of detail that is *almost* as good as Google Chrome's Developer Tools.

Runs well on iOS Safari, as well as on other mobile browsers - for as long as JavaScript is enabled in the browser.

How to install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vconsole

You will need NPM tools to install it, but not actually required to use NPM to build your project. You can simply install VConsole somewhere in a separate folder, and just copy-paste vconsole.min.js from it.

Once you inject it into your page, will look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="vconsole.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript>let vc = new VConsole(); // this will initialize it.</script>
```

Visually is very appealing, you will see green button in lower-right corner of your page on your mobile/desktop browser, which will open console overlay.

Very neat!

Of course, it does not provide you with ability to select an element, see calculated css etc., but if you are looking for console output and some network report, this one is really easy to use.

Comment: Made my day! Since jsconsole.com was shut down I was looking for a tool like this! Debugging for Iphone gives me always a tough time but this tool is awesome. By just adding a few lines to the page I finally get useful debug messages. Thank you :)

Comment: @user2718671 My pleasure!

Comment: This is a gem! Easiest solution by far if you just want some simple debugging.

Answer (score 6):

### October 2019

AFAIK, For recent IOS versions there is no overall solution for debugging IOS from a PC.

You can however use one of the following solutions:

1. Display console messages in the browser itself. As described [here](https://blog.chromium.org/2019/03/debugging-websites-in-chrome-for-ios.html) and in Sinisa's answer.
2. The "remotedebug-ios-webkit-adapter" doesn't work for debugging IOS 12+. It requires extra steps for IOS 11, and works for IOS 10 and perhaps older versions as well.

Comment: My current issue is that the in-app javascript console does not output anything from my other tabs in chrome on the iPad. Also, both your links lead to the same url. It is sad that one of the richest tech companies in the world can't figure out a way for developers to debug simple websites without the help of tech-savvy windows/linux users.

Comment: @JohnF, Not sure I understand your current issue.

Comment: JohnF. They want you to buy a Mac, you can debug from that

Answer (score 1):

I use PrePros for CSS preprocessing and it has a built in server for mobile debugging and web inspector. But this is only good for local sites even still...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it is often not an issue with mobile Safari only but Safari in general. In these cases it can help to try the normal Safari (for Windows) and see if the bugs appear there. If so, it's much easier to debug something by this way.

Comment: Testing on mac might help, but not on windows as safari is outdated and not maintained anymore.

Comment: On my iPad2 (iOS 8.3) in the advanced settings of Safari it says: "To use the WebInspector, connect to Safari on your computer using a cable and access your iPad from the Develop menu. You can enable the Develop menu in Safari's Advanced Preferences on your computer". I could enable the Develop menu on my Safari5.1.7 on Windows8. However from there I don't know how to start the debugger of a html page shown in the Safari of my iPad.

Comment: Stonecrusher: I don't think its the same developer mode as required to remotely debug on an iPad.

Comment: safari 5 is the latest available for windows. This version is completely outdated...

Answer (score 1):

**2021 update:**

The creator of RemoteDebug here. I've built a replacement for RemoteDebug called [Inspect](http://inspect.dev), which packages everything together in a pleasant experience and enables easy iOS web debugging from Windows, macOS, and Linux, with a few extra features like screencasting and wifi debugging.

http://inspect.dev

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options I've come across for debugging on iOS. They're not full step-through debuggers, but they offer a JS error log, console and some inspection tools:

#### 1. Eruda

By adding the following snippet to the top of your page:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eruda"></script>
<script>eruda.init();</script>
```

You get an interactive set of developer tools similar to those in Chrome and Firefox. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Eruda Screenshot]

Available at https://github.com/liriliri/eruda

#### 2. MiniConsole

This one I developed myself when I had not discovered another suitable option. It has less features, but it does the main things - capture JS errors, and allow you to run commands to inspect variables and object on your page.

Here's a demo:

[image]

It's activated by just placing this script tag on your page:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/SimonEast/MiniConsoleJS@main/console.js"></script>
```

Open source, GPL licence. Available at: https://github.com/SimonEast/MiniConsoleJS/

#### 3. vConsole

Another similar option that I've not really tried. Available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/vconsole with a live demo at http://wechatfe.github.io/vconsole/demo.html.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this on a PC, but you should be able to go to http://[DEVICE_IP_ADDRESS]:9999 to debug.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Can you point me to instructions/documentation regarding this?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe this will work. why port `9999`? doesn't even make sense

Comment: You don't need this anymore.  You can use the develop menu item.  This was the official way to do this 5 years ago.

Comment: @StephenJohnson What Develop menu and where?

Comment: @CsabaToth In Safari you need to open the Safari preferences, go to Advanced, and then toggle on "Show Develop menu in menu bar".

Comment: @StephenJohnson I think you are talking about OSX Safari and not iOS Safari. Is "Show Develop menu in menu bar" available on iPad Safari preferences somewhere? I cannot find it.

Comment: As far as I know it is not available in iPad Safari.