# How to play audio on IPad using Flash CC canvas project

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, html5-canvas, flash-cc

I'm using flash cc html5 project type. I built my project and tested on desktop and it works fine. Once test on ipad it does not play the audio. It works on android  devices but not my ipad 4. I'm using Mp3 files in my flash project.

I tried the safari & Chrome on my Ipad neither played the audio in my file.

Links to my files.

http://dev.wisc-online.com/prototypes/TestJosh/cis3405_html5.html
http://dev.wisc-online.com/prototypes/TestJosh/cis3405_html5.js

Comment: Did you try to [remote debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408110/debug-ipad-safari-with-a-pc) in Safari to see what error messages (if any) you get?

Comment: No I didnt try that. I did figure it out though. I had to launch the audio through code on a button. soundJS. You cant add it to the timeline in flash like you use to be able to.

Comment: Ill provide code for anyone whos interested.

Comment: You could create an answer with that information and mark it as accepted answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing the audio on the timeline frame like i was used to doing in flash you have to play the audio through code to get it to play on the Ipad with flash cc html5 projects. Also it needs to be triggered by a click or touch event now.

```
createjs.Sound.registerPlugins([createjs.WebAudioPlugin,   
createjs.FlashAudioPlugin]);
createjs.Sound.alternateExtensions = ["mp3"];
createjs.Sound.registerSound("sounds/slide1_01.mp3", "page1");
createjs.Sound.registerSound("sounds/slide2.mp3", "page2");
createjs.Sound.registerSound("sounds/ending.mp3", "page3");

var Vpage1 = createjs.Sound.play("page1");
var Vpage2 = createjs.Sound.play("page2");
var Vpage3 = createjs.Sound.play("page3");

this.Next.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_7.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_7() {
    createjs.Sound.stop();
    this.gotoAndStop(1);
    Vpage2.play();
}
```