# Ajax on Apple devices

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax

Hi this code below works perfetcly in all device not apple.

I don't know why... Can you help me?

It works on desktop pc and on mobile Android, but not in Apple devices...

I have an ipad that i use To test but i don't know how can I debug my code on It...

```
    $(document).on("touchstart click", "#btn", function(){

    $(document).off("touchstart click", "#btn");

    var data = $("#preview_form").serializeObject();

    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({

        "type": "POST",
        "url":  ajaxurl,
        "cache": false,
        "data": data,
        "beforeSend": function(){

            $(".my-lightbox-close").click();
            $("#wrapper").fadeOut();
            $("#result").css({"min-height":"500px"}).html("<div id='loading-animation-container'><p><span id='glow'></span><span id='light'></span><span id='stars'></span><span id='stars-2'></span><span id='small-stars'></span><span id='small-stars-2'></span></p><div class='loader'><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--text'></div></div></div>");


        },

        "success": function (result) {
                      window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/");
            return false;
        },
        "error": function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

});
```

I Think that the ajax request is processed because my lightbox disappear on click. But data is not sent, and the page si not refreshed...

Comment: Put that in the question, not a comment.

Comment: Enable the Web Inspector in iOS Safari to debug it.

Comment: I don't have a Mac. How Can i use web inspector from Windows?

Comment: Is your google broken? I found this when I googled "debug ios safari from windows": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20408110/debug-ipad-safari-with-a-pc

Comment: Hi. I'm using firebug droplets on safari. In The console There are not errors. But The ajax post request is never reported in console... why only on Apple device i have this issue?

Comment: If I knew the answer, I wouldn't be suggesting that you make use of a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: Ok But There are no errors in console... this code works... what a misteryous bug...

Comment: What you really want to do is use the Network tab of the web console, to see if the AJAX request is being sent and what parameters are in it.

Comment: Ajax request does never start

Comment: Are you sure the event handler is even running? Do you see `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Yes i See only data log. I have inserted a console.log in The success function But is Not shown

Comment: I can't think of any reason why the ajax request doesn't start when you call `$.ajax`.

Comment: If there were a general problem with `$.ajax` on mobile Safari, it would be well known.

Comment: Other previous requests are processed

Comment: I have removed The Close Light box click And The ajax request was processed. It sound Strange But still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed The Close Light box click And The ajax request was processed. It sound Strange But still works.

```
$(document).on("touchstart click", "#btn", function(){

$(document).off("touchstart click", "#btn");

var data = $("#preview_form").serializeObject();

console.log(data);

$.ajax({

    "type": "POST",
    "url":  ajaxurl,
    "cache": false,
    "data": data,
    "beforeSend": function(){

        //$(".my-lightbox-close").click();
        $("#wrapper").fadeOut();
        $("#result").css({"min-height":"500px"}).html("<div id='loading-animation-container'><p><span id='glow'></span><span id='light'></span><span id='stars'></span><span id='stars-2'></span><span id='small-stars'></span><span id='small-stars-2'></span></p><div class='loader'><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--dot'></div><div class='loader--text'></div></div></div>");


    },

    "success": function (result) {
                  window.location.replace("http://www.example.com/");
        return false;
    },
    "error": function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

});